# Помогите советом по разработке на Android

Tags: javascript, java

Хочу создать мобильное приложение для Googel Play на подобие Pinterest но с видео вместо картинок. **Вопрос:** какой язык выбрать Java или JavaScript(JS т.к. видео должны храниться в облаке)? В какой среде разработки это лучше сделать? Что нужно изучить для этого?

Comment: JavaScript не подойдёт. Он для браузера. Берите Java или Kotlin. IDE - AndroidStudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следует использовать Java. Среда разработки - Android Studio или Unity(По ней очень много обучающего материала в интернете). Стоит ещё изучить работы с базами данных.

Comment: Стоит отметить что Unity работает с C#, а не с Java, хотя эти языки и весьма схожи.